# Unrealscript tutorials for self-made maps

Tags: udk

I've been looking up tutorials for UnrealScript, but I'm very confused by what I find.

All tutorials seem to use Visual Studio and nFringe for the coding, plus the UDK editor for the maps.

Every tutorial I've come across seems to assume I want to either modify UT2004 or edit physics. This is not the case. I plan on making some custom maps in UDK with no textures or anything, and script some events for those maps. Lights turning on and off. Doors opening and closing. Walls shifting. That kind of stuff.

As such, the tutorials I've found are confusing and take up a lot of time and configuration I don't understand. Can someone get me on the right path for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level scripting is generally done through Kismet, not through Unrealscript.  Kismet is their visual scripting language that ties triggers/entities together and so forth.

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/KismetUserGuide.html

Comment: would this include interaction with NPCs and more complex events like walking to a monitor and the monitor screen taking up your entire screen to perform tasks on there that influence the map?

Comment: For NPCs I think you generally tie Kismet with Matinee.  http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MatineeUserGuide.html  For the second I think you can do all that with Kismet.  I haven't done anything that complicated with it, though.